# Illegal flagging of comments on a locked and deleted question

Tags: bug, comment, flagging

I can flag comments on [a locked and deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207152/sabrina-was-too-beautiful-for-numbers) despite being told the comment is not eligible for flagging.

Attempting to upvote the comment tells me I can't flag.

[image: upvoting attempt]

But I can flag it anyway

[image: flagging anyway]

And it appears in my flagging history

[image: pending]

Update: Flag was accepted and the comment I flagged is now completely gone.

Comment: Note: I first mistakenly posted this on [Updates to the site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/updates-to-the-site/20070#20070), and there user quid said they had verified this behavior on another site.

Comment: The  REflagging is irrelevant. It seems one can flag comments on deleted posts in general.  (Tested here, and on MO. Sorry to the mods for the noise.)

Comment: @quid Have you been getting the message "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging?" The only example I've found so far of this appearing elsewhere is on the same question I have given as an example ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207152/sabrina-was-too-beautiful-for-numbers)). Since I did not flag the remaining comment the first time, I agree that the issue appears to not be from reflagging. All the other deleted posts I've looked at just give me the message "comments on deleted [questions/answers] cannot be upvoted."

Comment: @quid I have updated the question to get rid of the reflagging statement.

Comment: The message is because the post is locked not only deleted; on deleted one it is a different warning. One might stress this locked. At least there is definitely *some* bug, as the documentation does not match the behavior.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEx5G-GOS1k